# How to get the String value from the function as my code gets the compile error 'Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment'

Tags: excel, vba

Below is my code to call the Function RandomBoysName to get the random name from the array of names in the function

```
Sub test()

Range("A1").Value = RandomBoysName

End Sub
```

Below is the function which returns the random boys name from the array.

```
Public Function RandomBoysName() As String

RandomBoysName = Array("Jacob", "Michael", "Joshua", "Matthew", "Christopher")

randArrIndex = Int((UCase(RandomBoysName) + 1) * Rnd)

RandomBoysName = "TEST"

RandomBoysName = RandomBoysName & RandomBoysName(randArrIndex)

End Function
```

Getting the error **Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment** in the below line

```
randArrIndex = Int((UCase(RandomBoysName) + 1) * Rnd)
```

Comment: `UCase` expects a string to turn into uppercase, not an array. Are you maybe getting it confused with `UBound`?

Comment: Also keep in mind that if you use `Rnd` without also using `Randomize` then you will not get a truly random number, and may actually get the same number every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think u are using the variables wrong

this code will help u

```
Public Function RandomBoysName() As String

BoysName = Array("Jacob", "Michael", "Joshua", "Matthew", "Christopher")
' the number 4 is the number of items in your array including the 0
randArrIndex = Int((4 * Rnd) + 1)

RandomBoysName = "TEST" & BoysName(randArrIndex)

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
Public Function RandomBoysName() As String
    Application.Volatile
    Randomize
    arr = Array("Jacob", "Michael", "Joshua", "Matthew", "Christopher")
    randArrIndex = Int((UBound(arr) + 1) * Rnd)
    RandomBoysName = "TEST"
    RandomBoysName = RandomBoysName & arr(randArrIndex)
End Function
```