# SQL Query to Find Unique Values After Where and GroupBy

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

Using AWS Athena to Query an aws_application table.

Table has things such as following

```
ID | Name 
server1  | Word 
server1  | Excel
server2  | Word 
server2  | Excel
server3  | Word 
server3  | Excel
server3  | Notepad
```

I'm looking for SQL Query that can list the server ID's (in this example) that DON'T have "Notepad" installed. The result should show.

```
ID
server1
server2
```

I'm new to this and so far I can only show which server has notepad. I thought I could somehow join the table to itself and subtract to try and get the unique ID's.

The above example is generic but easier to explain. In my exact I can run the following

```
select distinct resourceid
from aws_application
where name = 'Excel'
or name = 'Word'
group by resourceid
```

And get a total of 108 servers.

If I run

```
select distinct resourceid
from aws_application
group by resourceid
```

I get a unique count of 116 total servers. I want to return the number 8.

Of course there are thousands of lines in here as each line in the table represents a different application exe installed on the box.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59743762/12714427

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm looking for SQL Query that can tell me how many servers (in this example) DON'T have "Notepad" installed.

You can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select count(*)
from (select id, sum(case when name = 'Notepad' then 1 else 0 end) as num_notepad
      from aws_application a
      group by id
     ) s
where num_notepad = 0;
```

If you wanted the list and not the count:

```
select id, 
from aws_application a
group by id
having sum(case when name = 'Notepad' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

More typically, though, you would have a `servers` table.  Then you would do:

```
select count(*)
from servers s
where not exists (select 1
                  from aws_application a
                  where a.userid = s.userid and
                        a.name = 'Notepad'
                 );
```

Or for the list, use `select s.*` instead.

Comment: I actually want to show the ID's so I can use them later for further processing, not just the counts. I will edit and explain that better.

Comment: @mbspark . . . Your question explicitly asks for the *count* which is why I answered with that.  I amended the question for the list as well.

Comment: you are 100% right. I edited my desired result. My fault

Answer (score 1):

You could use `select distinct` and `not exists` for filtering:

```
select distinct id
from mytable t
where not exists (select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.id = t.id and t1.name = 'Notepad')
```

If you want the count of ids, then you can change `select distinct id` to `select count(distinct id)`. If you want the entire records, you can change it to `select t.*`

Another option is to use an anti-`left join`:

```
select distinct t.id
from mytable t
left join mytable t1 on t1.id = t.id and t1.name = 'Notepad'
where t1.id is null
```

Comment: how do I do this for more than one software application?

Comment: @mbspark: just expand the query with more `not exists` conditions.

Comment: @mbspark: no - `where not exists (select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.id = t.id and t1.name = 'Notepad') and not exists (select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.id = t.id and t1.name = 'Powerpoint')`